# why phaser game lagging in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I am creating my first game using Phaser and it is running fine in desktop.
But it is lagging on android phones.

can anyone tell me what could be the reasons?

game is very small 
smaller than 2mb.
Images used in game is also very tiny pngs.
is there anyway to find out any leaks in my code.

my main js file.

```
var buttetSpwanSpeed;
var bulletSpeed;
var enemySpwanSpeed;
var enemySpeed;
var golis;
var enemies;
var enemyLoop;
var scoreText;
var powers;
var bulletSize;
setStart();
//game phaser
var game=new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.CANVAS,"gamearea");
var BootState={
    //loding accets
    preload: function(){
        this.load.image('LodingScreen', 'assets/desimulga.png');
        this.load.image('background', 'assets/blue.png');
    },
    create: function(){
        game.state.start("LoadingState");
    },

};

var LoadingState={
    //loding acc
    preload: function(){
        bg=this.game.add.tileSprite(0,0,600,300,'background');
        bg.height = game.height;
        bg.width = game.width;
        LodingScreen=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY,'LodingScreen');
        LodingScreen.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        LodingScreen.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        this.load.image('spaceship', 'assets/player.png');
        this.load.image('goli', 'assets/bullet.png');
        //load ememies
        this.load.image('enemy1', 'assets/enemies/enemy1.png');
        this.load.image('enemy2', 'assets/enemies/enemy2.png');
        this.load.image('enemy3', 'assets/enemies/enemy3.png');
        this.load.image('enemy4', 'assets/enemies/enemy4.png');
        this.load.image('enemy5', 'assets/enemies/enemy5.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('power1', 'assets/power/bulletUp.png',34,33,4);

        this.load.image('restart', 'assets/restart.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('blast', 'assets/explosion.png',400,400,8);
        game.load.audio('fire', 'assets/music/bullet.mp3');
        game.load.audio('killed', 'assets/music/killed.mp3');
        //game.load.audio('bg_music', 'assets/music/background.mp3');
        game.load.audio('death_music', 'assets/music/death.mp3');
        game.load.audio('start_music', 'assets/music/start.mp3');
    },
    create: function(){
        game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, function(){
            bg.kill();
            LodingScreen.kill();
            game.state.start("PreGameState");
    },this);
    },

};

var PreGameState={
    //loding accets
    create: function(){
        game.scale.refresh();
        bg=this.game.add.tileSprite(0,0,600,300,'background');
        bg.height = game.height;
        bg.width = game.width;
        Startb=this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY, 'TAP TO START' , { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'yellow' });
        Startb.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        Startb.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        ship=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.height*0.4,'spaceship');
        ship.scale.setTo(0.4);
        ship.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(ship);
        bg.inputEnabled=true;

        start_music = game.add.audio('start_music');
        start_music.allowMultiple = true;
        start_music.addMarker('start_music', 0, 30);


        bg.events.onInputDown.add(function(){
            bg.inputEnabled=false;
            Startb.kill();
            start_music.play("start_music");
            // game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(ship, this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.height*0.8, 300, 3000);
            // game.add.tween(ship).to( { y: game.world.height*0.8 }, 3000, Phaser.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut, true);
            var tween = game.add.tween(ship).to({
            x: [this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.width*0, this.game.world.width, this.game.world.centerX],
            y: [this.game.world.height*0.4, this.game.world.height*0.5, this.game.world.height*0.6, this.game.world.height*0.8],
            }, 2000,Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.Out, true).interpolation(function(v, k){
                return Phaser.Math.bezierInterpolation(v, k);
            });

            game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, function() { 
                bg.kill();
                ship.kill();
                game.state.start("GameState");
            } ,this);

        }, this);
    },

};





var GameState={
    //loding accets
    preload: function(){


    },
    create: function(){
        //background
        this.background=this.game.add.tileSprite(0,0,600,300,'background');
        this.background.height = game.height;
        this.background.width = game.width;
        this.background.inputEnabled=true;
        this.background.input.enableDrag(true);
        this.background.input.startDrag = function(pointer) {
            pointer.shipStart = new Phaser.Point(GameState.ship.x, GameState.ship.y);
            Phaser.InputHandler.prototype.startDrag.call(this, pointer);
        };
        this.background.input.updateDrag = function(pointer) {
            GameState.ship.x = pointer.shipStart.x - pointer.positionDown.x + pointer.x;
            GameState.ship.y = pointer.shipStart.y - pointer.positionDown.y + pointer.y;
            GameState.background.x=0;
            GameState.background.y=0;
        };
        //ship
        this.ship=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.height*0.8,'spaceship');
        this.ship.scale.setTo(0.4);
        this.ship.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.ship);
        // this.ship.inputEnabled=true;
        // this.ship.input.enableDrag(true);
        //score
        this.scoreText = this.game.add.text(16, 16, 'Kills: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#fff' });
        //background Music
        // music = game.add.audio('bg_music');
        //music.play('', 0, 1, true);
        //bullet sound
        bullet_sound = game.add.audio('fire');
        bullet_sound.allowMultiple = true;
        bullet_sound.volume=0.5;
        bullet_sound.addMarker('fire', 0, 0.5);
        //Killed sound
        killed_sound = game.add.audio('killed');
        killed_sound.allowMultiple = true;
        killed_sound.addMarker('killed', 0, 0.5);
        //death music
        death_music = game.add.audio('death_music');
        death_music.allowMultiple = true;
        death_music.addMarker('death_music', 0, 10);
        //groups of bullets and enemies
        golis=game.add.group();
        enemies=game.add.group();
        powers=game.add.group();
        //fire bullet loop
        fireLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/buttetSpwanSpeed, fireBullet, this);
        //this.game.input.onTap.add(fireBullet, this);
        //create ememy loop
        enemyLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/enemySpwanSpeed, createEnemy, this);
        //change ememy speed and enemy spwan speed loop
        enemySpeedLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1.5, changeEnemySpeed, this);
        //give powerup
        powerUp=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*20, powerFun, this);      
    },
    update: function(){
        //scrolling background
        this.background.tilePosition.y+=2;

        //keybord control
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP))
        {
            this.ship.y-=2;
        }
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN))
        {
            this.ship.y+=2;
        }
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT))
        {
            this.ship.x+=2;
        }
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT))
        {
            this.ship.x-=2;
        }

        //dont go out
        if(this.ship.y<0+this.ship.height/2)
        {
            this.ship.y=0+this.ship.height/2;
        }
        if(this.ship.y>this.game.world.height-this.ship.height/2)
        {
            this.ship.y=this.game.world.height-this.ship.height/2;
        }

        if(this.ship.x<0+this.ship.width/2)
        {
            this.ship.x=0+this.ship.width/2;
        }
        if(this.ship.x>this.game.world.width-this.ship.width/2)
        {
            this.ship.x=this.game.world.width-this.ship.width/2;
        }
        //check for collisions 
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(golis,enemies,b_e_collide,null,this);
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship,enemies,s_e_collide,null,this);
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship,powers,s_power1_collide,null,this);




    },
};


//setting start game conditions
function setStart(){
    buttetSpwanSpeed=2;
    bulletSpeed=2000;
    enemySpwanSpeed=1;
    enemySpeed=300;
    score=0;
    bulletSize=1.2
}

//fire bullet function
function fireBullet(){
    goli=this.game.add.sprite(this.ship.x,this.ship.y-this.ship.height/2,'goli');
    goli.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    goli.scale.setTo(bulletSize,1);
    goli.checkWorldBounds = true;
    goli.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    //adding to group
    golis.add(goli);
    game.world.moveDown(goli);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(goli);
    goli.body.collisonWorldBounds=true;
    goli.body.velocity.y=-bulletSpeed;
    bullet_sound.play("fire");
}
//create enemy function
function createEnemy(){
    enemyNo=game.rnd.integerInRange(1, 5);
    x1=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    x2=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    enemy=this.game.add.sprite(x1,10,'enemy'+enemyNo);
    enemy.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    enemy.scale.setTo(0.4);
    enemy.checkWorldBounds = true;
    enemies.add(enemy);
    enemy.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    game.physics.arcade.enable(enemy);
    enemy.body.collisonWorldBounds=true;
    enemy.angle=90;
    enemy.no=enemyNo;

    //moving enemy
    angleRedian=game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(enemy, x2, this.game.world.height+enemy.height, enemySpeed,0);
    angleDegree=angleRedian*57.2958;
    enemy.angle=90+angleDegree;

}

//runs when bullet collide to enemy
function b_e_collide(goli,enemy){
    //blast
    blast=this.game.add.sprite(enemy.x,enemy.y,'blast');
    blast.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    blast.scale.setTo(0.5);
    var explosion=blast.animations.add('explosion');
    blast.animations.play('explosion',30,false,true);

    //killing
    goli.kill();
    enemy.kill();

    //update scores
    if(enemy.no<4)
    {
        score+=1;
        killed_sound.play('killed');
    }
    this.scoreText.text = 'Kills: ' + score;
}
//runs when ship collide to enemy
function s_e_collide(ship,enemy){

    blast=this.game.add.sprite(enemy.x,enemy.y,'blast');
    blast.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    blast.scale.setTo(0.5);
    var explosion=blast.animations.add('explosion');
    blast.animations.play('explosion',10,false,true);
    ship.kill();
    enemy.kill();
    //music.stop();
    this.scoreText.kill();
    death_music.play("death_music");
    game.time.events.remove(fireLoop);
    game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, function() {    
        fianlScore = this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY, 'KILL: '+score, { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'yellow' });
        fianlScore.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        gameOverText = this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY - fianlScore.height, 'GAME OVER', { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'red' });
        gameOverText.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        //restart button
        restart=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY + fianlScore.height+10,'restart');
        restart.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        restart.scale.setTo(0.05,0.05);
        restart.inputEnabled = true;
        restart.events.onInputDown.add(restartGame, this);
        game.time.events.stop();
    }, this);

}
//runs when ship collide power1
function s_power1_collide(ship,power){
    power.kill();
    game.time.events.remove(fireLoop);
    fireLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/10, fireBullet, this);
    game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 10, function(){
        game.time.events.remove(fireLoop);
        fireLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/buttetSpwanSpeed, fireBullet, this);
    },this);



}


function changeEnemySpeed()
{   
    if(enemySpeed<=900)
    {
        enemySpeed+=5;
    }
    if(enemySpwanSpeed<=3)
    {
        enemySpwanSpeed+=0.025;
    }
    enemyLoop.delay=Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/enemySpwanSpeed;
}

//send power up
function powerFun()
{
    x1=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    x2=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    power=this.game.add.sprite(x1,10,'power1');
    power.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    var shine=power.animations.add('shine');
    power.animations.play('shine',5,true,true);
    power.checkWorldBounds = true;
    power.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    powers.add(power);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(power);
    power.body.collisonWorldBounds=true;
    game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(power, x2, this.game.world.height+power.height, 400,0);
    powerDelay=game.rnd.integerInRange(20,35);
    powerUp.delay=Phaser.Timer.SECOND*powerDelay;
}



function restartGame(){
    setStart();
    game.time.events.start();
    game.state.start("PreGameState");   
}



game.state.add("GameState",GameState);
game.state.add("BootState",BootState);
game.state.add("LoadingState",LoadingState);
game.state.add("PreGameState",PreGameState);
game.state.start("BootState");
```

since the game is so small in size I think it should run smoothly on mobile devices.
it runs good on some high end mobile devices but gets slow as time progresses.
this is my first game so I am not very good with game designing concepts.

Comment: This would probably fit [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) more.

Comment: ok i will post there

Comment: When you say "small in size", are you talking the file size or the memory usage? Because the file size of your game isn't really an indicator of whether it will use a lot of memory or processing power.

Comment: so is there any way I can find memory or processing power my game using ?

Comment: Chrome has a built in "Task manager" which will give you the basic memory and CPU usage stats. There are also more in depth performance tools in the Dev-Tools menu, if you wanted more detail.

Comment: ok i will try them

Comment: task manager on chrome shows that my game is using 22% of processing of my macbook and around 170mb memory.

is it bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I currently got this issue fixed myself for my games cross platform.

Things I did were

Load alll sprites right at my main screen/or loading screen 
If you have reusable sprites use the command .kill() not .destory() which will take more memory to reload sprite unless the sprite is not coming back to screen then it’s ok to destroy.
Recycle everything let’s say you use a bullet asoon as it hits the wall boom kill and get it back.

And sad part in some cases even by doing sometimes it’ll still lag and have some glitches here and there you just have to see at what point is happening. Use break points to see exactly what sprites are causing it and consider also if the image doesn’t have transparency to use .jpeg

Good luck hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile phone the processing capacity is lower than in the desktop.

Generally the architecture of a mobile Cpu is usually optimized to save energy. When you are on a desktop, the x86 or x64 architecture is optimized for processing of data.

Therefore it is very important to test the performance of the application on the target device.

You need to reduce creation of objects, loading images or objects when the game is playing. I have better experience with my game just hidging and showing the same objects (enemies), instead of destroying objects (Enemies or Visual elements) and creating again while play. Because when a game create a new instance, the CPU load the same again. This change no make diference in high CPU but is very better in low CPU. Maybe it help you.

Comment: i think there is some leak in my code which i can not find

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine on your desktop, most likely it's an issue with the asset sizes being too big.  Reduce all of your assets 1/2 of the size.  Phaser has to load all of the assets into cache, then it reduces the pixel size of those files in the engine.

Comment: all my assets are around 4kb of sizes only musics are around 30 kb.
is it too big?

Comment: It def could be the problem. Also in your code you seem to have lots of physics objects on the screen.  Try reducing the amount of physics bodies and see if that helps performance.

Comment: what you mean by It def?

Comment: It definitely could